# What is the meaning of intended travel date in UK Visa application form: the starting date from own country or arrival date in UK?

Tags: visas, uk

In online application form (UK standard Visitor Visa) , I find two different word. 
i) Intended travel date ii) date of arrival in Uk. 
Do these two term has same meaning? 
I have no confusion on arrival date in UK. But does intended travel date meant for when I will start from my own country? or it is for  when I will arrive at UK.

Comment: You’re splitting hairs. For some people with short journeys it is the same, for some with long journeys it is a day or more later. Your travel date is when you commenced your journey. Arrival date is self explanatory.

Comment: The UK doesn't cae where you come from and how you've gotten to their border, so obviously it's when you want to arrive in the UK that matters when applying for a UK visa.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on an itinerary, the *intended date of travel* and *date of arrival in the UK* may be the same, or within a day or two, if one is going directly to the UK from their home country (or country of residence). However, for some, travel plans may include other destinations (one or more countries) before entry into the UK.

Answer (score 1):

Intended travel date = the date that you start to travel

Date of arrival = the date that you come to the destination

Answer (score 0):

"Intended travel date" is used to defer the visa start date for the maximum of 3 months from the date of application submission. "Date of arrival in the UK" is exactly that - the date you arrive in the UK based on your booking/itinerary (if any).